# docker compose - unauthorized: unauthorized to access repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm having issues using docker compose with private repositories.

Looking for similar issues i can't get --verbose to give any meaningful output, to help debugging the issue.

When i use docker compose to pull images from a private registry i receive the error:

> "Error response from daemon: unauthorized: unauthorized to access
> repository: myrepo/myservice, action: pull: unauthorized to access
> repository: myrepo/myservice, action: pull"

I've made sure to run the docker login command, before running docker compose up.

If i run docker pull on the image described in the compose file, the image is downloaded as expected, but running docker compose up fails.

i'm using docker for windows.
docker compose version 2.13.
docker version:

```
PS C:\Users\kov\source\repos\localsetup> docker version
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.29
 Version:           20.10.21
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.18.7
 Git commit:        baeda1f
 Built:             Tue Oct 25 18:08:16 2022
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Desktop 4.15.0 (93002)
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.21
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.18.7
  Git commit:       3056208
  Built:            Tue Oct 25 18:00:19 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.10
  GitCommit:        770bd0108c32f3fb5c73ae1264f7e503fe7b2661
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.4
  GitCommit:        v1.1.4-0-g5fd4c4d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

my docker compose file:

```
services:
  appRestApiEndpoint:
    image: myregistry.io/repo/app-rest-api-endpoint
    container_name: my-service
    ports:
      - 5000:80
    networks:
      - backend
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=myEnvVariable
  
networks:
  backend:
```

Comment: I guess you are not alone: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3683

Comment: I've found that issue too, and tried the verbose flag to get some output from the command. Given that it's from  2016 i assumed the active parties in that issue must have found a solution since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can provide you with the following solution / workaround, though I'm not sure if this is the "wanted" behavior of docker-compose or a bug; see the link I mentioned above.

Create the following config file

- For Linux I know the file is: `~/.docker/config.json`
- For Windows it might be similar to `C:\Users\<username>\.docker\config.json`

#### Example for Docker Hub registry:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "https://index.docker.io/v1/": {
            "auth": "<auth-string>"
        }
    }
}
```

`<auth-string>` is the base64-encoded string: `<docker-loginname>:<auth-token>`. The `<auth-token>` can be generated by logging into docker hub.

#### Example for Harbor docker registry:

```
{
    "auths": {
        "<harbor-url": {
            "auth": "<auth-string>"
        }
    }
}
```

`<auth-string>` is `base64(<loginname>:<password>)`

Comment: is <auth-token>missing from your example ? i don't see where that is used, or is it synonym with auth-string.

Comment: It is all there: base64(<docker-loginname>:<auth-token>) => <auth-string>

Comment: Right, missed that. our private registry is hosted with something called harbor, and i can't create an auth token in that ui, as described for dockerhub https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/access-tokens/

Comment: In my company we also use harbor. Our jenkins uses the config file the same way.

Comment: I updated my answer for harbor. You are welcome to mark my answer as useful, if it helped.